# Limitar número de ocorrências do Group By

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho que buscar em uma tabela dados de um anunciante, preciso agrupar pelo anunciante de acordo com os mais vistos, separados pela data.

Eu queria limitar o `group by`, tem como?

Tabela exemplo:

```
id       visualizacoes       data
485            19            20/05/2105
485            68            11/03/2105
121            45            05/04/2105
485            20            20/05/2105
370            37            26/05/2105
225            81            20/05/2105
485            75            07/03/2105
485            11            20/05/2105
485            46            20/05/2105
370            23            16/04/2105
370            15            09/05/2105
121            7             21/04/2105
680            10            20/05/2105
370            68            26/05/2105
370            92            26/05/2105
```

Quero agrupar pelo `id_anunciante` e somar as visualizações com mesma data, mas queria limitar até 3 registros por anunciante.

Query inicial:

```
SELECT *, SUM(visualizacoes) AS total_visu 
FROM anunciante 
GROUP BY id,data
```

Comment: Poste a query que você já desenvolveu para buscar esses dados

Comment: essa query traz o resultado certo, por exemplo o id 485 tem 4 registros do dia 20/05/2015 quero apenas 3. Então de 3 em 3 ids.

Comment: Acho que dá pra resolver com uma query simples. Mas não ficou totalmente claro pra mim o que você quer. Você mostrou como está a sua tabela, se da mesma maneira você mostrar como ficaria o resultado do SELECT eu posso oferecer uma resposta.

Comment: Ok Caffé,  no meu resultado, trás tudo agrupado pela data e somando as visualizações ,certo, então supondo que a tabela trouxe 20 resultados, desses 5 são do id 485, aí nesse caso eu quero que seja apenas 3 registros, entendeu?

Comment: @Rafael Sim, entendi. E já temos uma resposta aceita :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão o MySQL não faz isso, mas podemos improvisar.

Supondo que sua consulta original seja essa

```
SELECT id, data, SUM(visualizacoes)
FROM tabela
GROUP BY id, data 
ORDER BY id, data DESC;
```

Coloque sua consulta em uma subquery, será acrescentada uma coluna extra que contará a repetição de determinado `id`:

```
SELECT id, data, totalVisualizacoes,
@currcount := IF(@currvalue = id, @currcount + 1, 1) AS rank,
@currvalue := id FROM (
    SELECT id, data, SUM(visualizacoes) AS totalVisualizacoes
    FROM tabela
    GROUP BY id, data 
    ORDER BY id, data DESC;
) AS totais;
```

Por fim, faça a consulta final que irá filtrar o número de ocorrências:

```
SELECT id, data, totalVisualizacoes FROM (
    SELECT id, data, totalVisualizacoes,
    @currcount := IF(@currvalue = id, @currcount + 1, 1) AS rank,
    @currvalue := id FROM (
        SELECT id, data, SUM(visualizacoes) AS totalVisualizacoes
        FROM tabela
        GROUP BY id, data
        ORDER BY id, data DESC
    ) AS totaisPorData
) AS totalLimitado
WHERE rank <= 3;
```

Exemplo no [slqfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc3ef/3).

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269273/2099835)

Comment: interessante sua resposta, muito bom, mas testei aqui e me aparece 4 ocorrências do exemplo do id 485, mesmo que no final tenha o "rank<=3"

Comment: Verdade, faltou o ORDER BY... corrigido

Comment: mesmo assim não deu certo, vc conseguiu testar?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc3ef/3 - Funciona exatamente com as informações que você postou. Se o objetivo é somente contar, certifique que só as colunas necessárias estão no select e no group by.

Comment: no seu exemplo deu certo mesmo, testei no sqlfiddle, mas no meu servidor do phpMyAdmin não deu, mostrou mais resultados, será que é a versão do mysql? a minha é 5.5.42. No site sqlfiddle é 5.5 ou 5.6, tem alguma coisa a ver?

Comment: Não, o problema deve ser a quantidade de colunas que você está utilizando. Tente não utilizar o `*` e caso precise de mais colunas, insira elas no ORDER BY.

Comment: Valeu, coloquei a mesma quantidade de coluna deu certo, show de bola!

Answer (score 0):

Estava com um problema bem parecido e não consegui resolver através da [resposta do gmsantos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66389/64665), no entanto encontrei outra resposta bem semelhante pelo usuário [Salman A (link para a resposta)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269273/6322156), foi então que consegui entender direito como funciona a contagem de ocorrências de um valor em um campo específico, funcionou 100% para mim!
Preste atenção na primeira linha onde tem:

```
SET @currcount = NULL, @currvalue = NULL;
```

esta linha precisa sempre estar presente para a contagem de ocorrências funcionar. (Caso você estiver editando o sql no phpmyadmin essa linha vai desaparecer se você executar a query e clicar em editar novamente)

*Obs.: Meu problema era selecionar as 20 últimas ofertas de cada empresa no banco*