# Limitar ocorrências de registros para cada tipo

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou precisando limitar o número de ocorrências de cada tipo de material que tenho no meu banco de dados.

Segue a query abaixo com o que quero fazer:

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID, NOME, TIPO FROM TB_MATERIAIS WHERE TIPO = 1
SELECT TOP 10 ID, NOME, TIPO FROM TB_MATERIAIS WHERE TIPO = 2
SELECT TOP 10 ID, NOME, TIPO FROM TB_MATERIAIS WHERE TIPO = 3
SELECT TOP 10 ID, NOME, TIPO FROM TB_MATERIAIS WHERE TIPO = 4
```

Como podem ver, eu quero as 10 primeiras ocorrências de cada tipo de material na minha consulta.

**Mas estou precisando fazer com que isso vire uma query só.** No caso, preciso que venham as 10 primeiras ocorrências de cada tipo na mesma query.

Como posso fazer isso? Com CASE WHEN é possível fazer um contador para cada tipo de material? Até fiz uns teste, mas sem sucesso. Acho que minha lógica não está dando certo nessa questão.

Infelizmente não consegui extrair uma resposta da pergunta abaixo

[Limitar número de ocorrências do Group By](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66379/limitar-n%C3%BAmero-de-ocorr%C3%AAncias-do-group-by)

Comment: os tipos são fixo?

Comment: sim, só existem esses 4.

Comment: a solução do Sorack, deve solucionar o seu problema obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `ROW_NUMBER` com agrupamento da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.TIPO  ORDER BY m.ID) as sequencia,
              m.*
         FROM TB_MATERIAIS m) x
 WHERE x.sequencia <= 10;
```

Comment: Não pude comentar antes, meu problema foi resolvido! Deu certinho!

Comment: Já foi nas duas :)

Comment: Opa beleza, valeu :)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48654/discussion-on-answer-by-sorack-limitar-ocorrencias-de-registros-para-cada-tipo)

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [`UNION ALL`](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/945/sql-utilizando-o-operador-union-e-union-all.aspx), que vai combinar os resultados sem a execução no final de um [`distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms132161(v=sql.120).aspx) trazendo os dados mesmo se houver repetição, acredito que no seu caso isso já resolva. Se por ventura não quiser repetição utilize somente [`UNION`](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/945/sql-utilizando-o-operador-union-e-union-all.aspx)

> **Como ficaria então sua SQL**?

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID, NOME, TIPO FROM TB_MATERIAIS WHERE TIPO = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10 ID, NOME, TIPO FROM TB_MATERIAIS WHERE TIPO = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10 ID, NOME, TIPO FROM TB_MATERIAIS WHERE TIPO = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10 ID, NOME, TIPO FROM TB_MATERIAIS WHERE TIPO = 4
```

<sub>**Oservação:** a resposta @Sorack é justa para SQLServer e perfeita, mas, a minha server para diversos bancos, acredito que a diversidade de respostas corretas e que solucionam o problema são válidas.</sub>

**Referencias:**

- [UNION (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180026.aspx)
- [SQL: Utilizando o Operador UNION e UNION ALL](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/945/sql-utilizando-o-operador-union-e-union-all.aspx)

Comment: Opa Virgilio, acho que é algo desse tipo mesmo. O TOP já faz o limite para mim e o union all junta todos os resultados para mim, certo?

Comment: @DiChrist sim ... !!! é da forma que descreveu

Comment: Nesta solução a tabela TB_MATERIAIS terá que ser lida 4 vezes; isto não é eficiente. Além disso, se um novo tipo de material for registrado, o código ficará obsoleto.

Comment: O `row_number()` é para SqlServer e a minha resposta serve para diversos bancos é um padrão universal, se o código do tipo vai ficar obsoleto pode acontecer é um fato, mas, se for diferente de `SQLServer` o que você disse também não vale. Lembro que respostas universal também tem sua valia, inclusive vou editar esse comentario, obrigado.