# Dúvida com group by para último registro

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu quero fazer um `select` que traga os dados de nota de cada aluno, agrupado por aluno e matéria, porém eu quero apenas o resultado da última prova de cada matéria. Por exemplo um aluno pode fazer a prova de inglês 3 vezes, e de matemática duas vezes, nos resultados deve mostrar os dados da última prova de inglês e matemática.

As colunas devem ser: aluno, aula, data de realização da última prova e nota.

Se eu não colocar a coluna "nota" no `group by` dá erro, mas se eu colocar mostra os resultados de todas as provas, não apenas da última.

```
 select 
   aluno, aula, max(data) as data, nota
  from notas
  group by aluno, aula
  order by aluno, aula
```

Scripts de create e insert

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[notas](
    [aluno] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [aula] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [data] [datetime] NULL,
    [nota] [decimal](18, 1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT [dbo].[notas] ([aluno], [aula], [data], [nota]) VALUES (N'JOSE', N'ING1', CAST(N'2016-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(4.0 AS Decimal(18, 1)))
INSERT [dbo].[notas] ([aluno], [aula], [data], [nota]) VALUES (N'CARLOS', N'ING1', CAST(N'2016-12-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(6.0 AS Decimal(18, 1)))
INSERT [dbo].[notas] ([aluno], [aula], [data], [nota]) VALUES (N'JOSE', N'ING1', CAST(N'2016-12-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(7.0 AS Decimal(18, 1)))
INSERT [dbo].[notas] ([aluno], [aula], [data], [nota]) VALUES (N'CARLOS', N'MAT', CAST(N'2016-12-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(5.6 AS Decimal(18, 1)))
INSERT [dbo].[notas] ([aluno], [aula], [data], [nota]) VALUES (N'JOSE', N'ING1', CAST(N'2016-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(4.0 AS Decimal(18, 1)))
INSERT [dbo].[notas] ([aluno], [aula], [data], [nota]) VALUES (N'JOSE', N'MAT', CAST(N'2016-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(6.0 AS Decimal(18, 1)))
INSERT [dbo].[notas] ([aluno], [aula], [data], [nota]) VALUES (N'JOSE', N'MAT', CAST(N'2016-12-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(8.0 AS Decimal(18, 1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se é a query com melhor desempenho, mas acredito que resolvi o seu problema:

```
select T1.* 
from notas T1
inner join (select aluno, aula, max(data) as data
            from notas
            group by aluno, aula
            ) T2 on T1.aluno = T2.aluno and T1.aula = T2.aula and T1.data = T2.data
Order by aluno, aula, data
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou!

Answer (score 3):

Com [***`ROW_NUMBER()`***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()
     OVER(PARTITION BY aluno, aula ORDER BY data DESC) as sequencia from notas
) F WHERE sequencia = 1
```

***Referencias:***

- [ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [ROW_NUMBER – How To Use It](http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/row_number-how-to-use-it/)
- [Como dinamicamente Numerar linhas em uma instrução Transact-SQL](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/186133)
- [Trouble using ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY …)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921327/trouble-using-row-number-over-partition-by)
- [Limitar ocorrências de registros para cada tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165751/limitar-ocorr%C3%AAncias-de-registros-para-cada-tipo)

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou!

Comment: @Murilo: Como as colunas aluno e aula constam de PARTITION BY, não é necessário (e nem faz sentido) que estas duas colunas também constem em ORDER BY. // Fica assim: PARTITION BY aluno, aula ORDER BY data DESC

Comment: @JoséDiz o seu comentário é pertinente, eu já alterei a linha aonde você fez a observação. Apesar da observação, tanto faz, inclusive o plano de execução (todas as vezes que faço SQL, tenho esse cuidado) da na mesma.